# Google Script to change Image Over Cell based on data validation input

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google sheets I have a data validation range set that when an item is selected the corresponding image is displayed using a vlookup from a range of pictures. I want to use that pic to auto populate a floating image (Image over cell) and have that image over cell change as the data validation item selection changes.  Is there a way to tie a vlookup to that floating image?  Or do I have to use a script?  The current script I am using is below.  It runs but is there a way to select that specific image? It currently selects another image.

Thank you!

```
function myImage() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var images = sheet.getImages();
  var image = images[images.length - 1];
  image.setAnchorCell(sheet.getRange('A14'))
  .setAnchorCellXOffset(60)
  .setAnchorCellYOffset(-21);
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this method is included in your goal, I proposed a sample method for retrieving the specific image from a sheet. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am trying to access a pic from within the current sheet.  Uploading from a website is not possible. Is there a way to call a specific image this is place in a specific cell?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the title and the description of the image, you can retrieve the specific image using them. For example, as a sample script for retrieving the specific image using the title of the image, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set a sample title of "sampleTitle" to the specific image you want to retrieve.

```js
function myImage() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var title = "sampleTitle"; // Please set the image title.
  var image = sheet.getImages().find(e => e.getAltTextTitle() == title);
  if (!image) return;

  // do someting.
  image.setAnchorCell(sheet.getRange('A14'))
    .setAnchorCellXOffset(60)
    .setAnchorCellYOffset(-21);
  
  
  // If you want to replace the retrieved image with other image, you can use the following script.
  image.replace("Blob or URL").setAltTextTitle("sampleTitle");
}
```

#### Note:

- When you put a new image with the title, you can use the following sample script.

  ```
    sheet.insertImage("Blob or URL", 1, 1).setAltTextTitle("sampleTitle")
  ```

#### References:

- [getAltTextTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getAltTextTitle())
- [getAltTextDescription()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getalttextdescription)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I am trying to access a pic from within the current sheet. Uploading from a website is not possible. Is there a way to call a specific image this is place in a specific cell?

I understood that you wanted to change an image on Spreadsheet with another image on Spreadsheet. In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, in order to detect the image, the title of the image is used.

In this sample script, the image with the title of `sampleTitle1` is replaced with the image with the title of `sampleTitle2`.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please give the title to 2 images you want to replace. And, please set the variable of `obj`, and run the script.

```js
function sample() {
  var obj = { "from": "sampleTitle1", "to": "sampleTitle2" };  // Please set the image titles.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var titles = Object.values(obj);
  var images = sheet.getImages().reduce((o, e) => {
    if (titles.includes(e.getAltTextTitle())) {
      ["from", "to"].forEach(f => {
        if (obj[f] == e.getAltTextTitle()) o[f] = e;
      });
    }
    return o;
  }, {});
  if (Object.keys(images).length != 2) {
    throw new Error("Images for replacing cannot be found.");
  }
  const fromImage = images.from.getAnchorCell();
  const toImage = images.to.getAnchorCell();
  images.from.setAnchorCell(toImage);
  images.to.setAnchorCell(fromImage);
}
```

- When this script is run, the image of `sampleTitle1` is replaced with the image of `sampleTitle2`. So, when you run this script again, the images are replaced again.